# Pycharm window "flashing"

Tags: pycharm

Every few seconds the pyCharm application blinks for a millisecond and flashes white. Has anyone else come across this error and know how to fix it?
I'm using OSX, Pycharm Community Edition 4.5.3

Comment: What version of PyCharm are you using? Version number, community edition or professional? What OS? This is simply not enough information for us to help you...

Comment: I'm using OSX, PyCharm edition 4.5.3 community edition
Sorry my bad

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bug that JetBrains need to fix, i've looked around and found people having this issue with IntelliJ, PyCharm and PhpStorm.

They are aware of it (for a while now) but have not yet found a solution by the looks of it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131593

Answer (score 2):

It is 2023, and it still happening on:

macOS Big Sur, 11.7.2

Pycharm 2022.3.1

Only on fullscreen.
As the previous answer from @Jorick, from the link states you need to use JDK8 other than the Apple one